# Zend Framework-Best way to hide Controller name

Tags: url, zend-framework

I am getting one problem in zend framework. I want to hide *controller name* in my *zend framework url*.

For Example https://example.com/index/about-us

I want to hide index controller from my url and i want url like

https://example.com/about-us

*index* is my default controller and *about-us* is my method

I have tried following code but it doesn't help

i have put this code in */application/Bootstrap.php*

```
public function _initCustomRoute(){

 $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
  $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':action', array(
    'module'     => 'default',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'index'
    ));
$router->addRoute('default-override', $route);


}
```

**please help me to solve this problem.**